# profiles with sessions php

Tags: php, session, search

recently I've added a search feature to find users through my database and I encountered a question upon selecting the searched user:

-Example: John Doe searches for a user; John Doe then clicks the link to go to the users profile (view_profile.php). -Should I be echoing out all the info I want to display about the searched user via using mysql_fetch_array($username) and storing all desired info in session variables?

Should I be passing session variables to create profiles for other users to view. Or should every profile have it's own file? Thanks.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use `mysql_fetch_array()`, use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Guess I forgot to mention that I'm using a web browser whom does not support mysqli_* (deprecated php). I forgot I had to mention that in every post ...

Comment: Do you mean web server? Your browser shouldn't be having any effect on how you connect to a database...

Answer (score 0):

Set the Link that comes up when a user is searched to:

```
<a href="view_profile.php?userId=*put user id here*">*put user name here*</a>
```

When the User clickes the link, PHP should get the users row from the database with:

```
$_GET['userId'];
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = *put user id here*
```

Don't use $_SESSION variables for this.
Hope this helped you out.

Comment: This just brings me to my profile, no matter what id I reference